# Group-specific computations in multi-step/nested grouping scenarios

Tags: r, filtering, grouping, cumulative-sum

I guess I'm trying to compute cumulative sums on certain data segments/groups where the grouping needs to happen in multiple cycles and in that sense, is somewhat nested (sorry, I don't know how better to describe it).

I'm trying to get from this

```
struc <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
  0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), X3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), row.names = c(NA, 
  -19L), class = "data.frame")
> struc
   X1 X2 X3
1   1  0  0
2   0  1  0
3   0  0  1
4   0  0  1
5   0  1  0
6   0  0  1
7   0  0  1
8   1  0  0
9   0  1  0
10  1  0  0
11  1  0  0
12  0  1  0
13  1  0  0
14  0  1  0
15  1  0  0
16  0  1  0
17  0  0  1
18  0  1  0
19  0  0  1
```

to this

```
> data.frame(
  x1 = cumsum(struc[,1]),
  x2 = c(0, rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), 0, 1, rep(0, 2), 1, 0, 1, 0, rep(1, 2), rep(2, 2)),
  x3 = c(rep(0, 2), 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, rep(0, 9), 1, 0, 1) 
)
   x1 x2 x3
1   1  0  0
2   1  1  0
3   1  1  1
4   1  1  2
5   1  2  0
6   1  2  1
7   1  2  2
8   2  0  0
9   2  1  0
10  3  0  0
11  4  0  0
12  4  1  0
13  5  0  0
14  5  1  0
15  6  0  0
16  6  1  0
17  6  1  1
18  6  2  0
19  6  2  1
```

---

### EDIT

**Background**

I'm using the info in `struc` to come up with a fast way to compute sort of an index matrix that tells me about the structure of **arbitrary** deeply nested lists and that I could use for `<-` and `[[` operations on those lists:

```
x <- list(
  x1 = list(x11 = list(x111 = 1, x112 = 1), x12 = list(x121 = 1, x122 = 1)),
  b = list(c = 2),
  c = 3,
  d = list(1:4),
  list(1:5),
  list(list(1:2), list(3:4))
)

getStructure <- function(x) {
  struc <- capture.output(str(x))
  struc <- unlist(strsplit(struc, split = "\n"))
  tops <- str_count(struc, "\\s\\$\\s")
  subs <- str_count(struc, "((\\.\\.)(\\s|\\$))")
  ## Clean //
  idx_out <- which(tops == 0 & subs == 0)
  if (length(idx_out)) {
    tops <- tops[-idx_out]
    subs <- subs[-idx_out]
    struc <- struc[-idx_out]
  }
  ## Levels //
  subs_2 <- lapply(0:subs[which.max(subs)], function(ii) {
    out <- subs == ii
    out[out] <- 1
    out
  })
  names(subs_2) <- 1:length(subs_2)
  data.frame(subs_2)
}
```

The best I could come up with so far is to loop over the columns in a certain way, but it feels like I'm not using the power of clever matrix algebra or the power of `dplyr` or things like `filter()` and similar "split-and-combine" approaches:

```
getIndexMatrix <- function(x) {
  for (ii in 1:ncol(x)) {
    if (ii == 1) {
      x[,ii] <- cumsum(x[,ii])
    } else {
      f <- factor(apply(x[,1:(ii-1), drop = FALSE], 1, paste, collapse = "-"))
      spl <- split(x, f = f)
      out <- lapply(spl, function(ii) {
        apply(ii, 2, cumsum)
      })
      x[,ii] <- do.call("rbind", out)[,ii]  
    }
    NULL
  }
  x
}
(indexes <- getIndexMatrix(struc))
   X1 X2 X3
1   1  0  0
2   1  1  0
3   1  1  1
4   1  1  2
5   1  2  0
6   1  2  1
7   1  2  2
8   2  0  0
9   2  1  0
10  3  0  0
11  4  0  0
12  4  1  0
13  5  0  0
14  5  1  0
15  6  0  0
16  6  1  0
17  6  1  1
18  6  2  0
19  6  2  1
```

This could for example be used to retrieve the "leaf" values of a nested list.

Auxiliary function:

```
getExtendedIndexMatrix <- function(x) {
  x <- getIndexMatrix(x)
  substituteZeros <- function(x) {
    x[!x] <- NA
    x
  }
  tmp <- as.data.frame(apply(x, 2, substituteZeros))
  spl <- split(tmp, f = tmp[,1])
  tmp <- lapply(spl, function(ii) {
    info <- lapply(1:nrow(ii), function(ii2) {
      data.frame(
        scope = length(na.omit(as.numeric(ii[ii2,,drop = TRUE]))),
        index = paste0("[[", paste(na.omit(as.numeric(ii[ii2,,drop = TRUE])), 
          collapse = "]][["), "]]")
      )
    })
    info <- do.call("rbind", info)
    leaf <- rep(FALSE, nrow(info))
    leaf[which(info$scope == which.max(info$scope))] <- TRUE
    data.frame(ii, leaf = leaf, info)
  })
  do.call("rbind", tmp)
}
> getExtendedIndexMatrix(struc)
     X1 X2 X3  leaf scope           index
1.1   1 NA NA FALSE     1           [[1]]
1.2   1  1 NA FALSE     2      [[1]][[1]]
1.3   1  1  1  TRUE     3 [[1]][[1]][[1]]
1.4   1  1  2  TRUE     3 [[1]][[1]][[2]]
1.5   1  2 NA FALSE     2      [[1]][[2]]
1.6   1  2  1  TRUE     3 [[1]][[2]][[1]]
1.7   1  2  2  TRUE     3 [[1]][[2]][[2]]
2.8   2 NA NA FALSE     1           [[2]]
2.9   2  1 NA  TRUE     2      [[2]][[1]]
3     3 NA NA  TRUE     1           [[3]]
4.11  4 NA NA FALSE     1           [[4]]
4.12  4  1 NA  TRUE     2      [[4]][[1]]
5.13  5 NA NA FALSE     1           [[5]]
5.14  5  1 NA  TRUE     2      [[5]][[1]]
6.15  6 NA NA FALSE     1           [[6]]
6.16  6  1 NA FALSE     2      [[6]][[1]]
6.17  6  1  1  TRUE     3 [[6]][[1]][[1]]
6.18  6  2 NA FALSE     2      [[6]][[2]]
6.19  6  2  1  TRUE     3 [[6]][[2]][[1]]
```

Actual leaf values:

```
getLeafValues <- function(x) {
  indexes <- getExtendedIndexMatrix(getStructure(x))
  expr <- parse(text = paste0("x", indexes[which(indexes$leaf), "index"]))
  lapply(expr, eval)
}
getLeafValues(x)
```

Comment: It looks to me like column 1 of the result is just `cumsum(struc$X1)`, and column 2 of the result is just the cumsum of col 2 of `struc`, grouped by `cumsum(X1)`. It's not clear what `$x3` is though, in particular how do you get the last two rows of that column??

Comment: The second data frame is sort of an index matrix of the underlying list (think of it as something you could use in `[[`: `x[[1]][[1]][[2]]` when transforming it a bit further). And yeah, I think I screwed up the last two lines, sorry! Corrected it.

Comment: Edit your question to correct this. Why are `x` or `getStructure(...)` relevant? You want to convert `struc` to the final result, no? That's the question, isn't it??

Comment: Sure, but what's wrong with making it as easy as possible to reproduce the specific data frames?? Otherwise you'd have to type it.

Comment: Bit of a side bar to the question, but a good way to provide data for R questions on SO is to include the output of, e.g., `dput(struc)` in in the question.

Comment: Ah, nice. Didn't think of that, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but here is a data.table solution that produces the same result as your example.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(struc)
struc[,x1:=cumsum(X1)]
struc[,x2:=cumsum(X2),by=x1]
struc[,x3:=cumsum(X3),by=with(rle(x2),rep(1:length(lengths),lengths))]
struc
#    X1 X2 X3 x1 x2 x3
#  1:  1  0  0  1  0  0
#  2:  0  1  0  1  1  0
#  3:  0  0  1  1  1  1
#  4:  0  0  1  1  1  2
#  5:  0  1  0  1  2  0
#  6:  0  0  1  1  2  1
#  7:  0  0  1  1  2  2
#  8:  1  0  0  2  0  0
#  9:  0  1  0  2  1  0
# 10:  1  0  0  3  0  0
# 11:  1  0  0  4  0  0
# 12:  0  1  0  4  1  0
# 13:  1  0  0  5  0  0
# 14:  0  1  0  5  1  0
# 15:  1  0  0  6  0  0
# 16:  0  1  0  6  1  0
# 17:  0  0  1  6  1  1
# 18:  0  1  0  6  2  0
# 19:  0  0  1  6  2  1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just trying to have a fast way of knowing about the dims of arbitrary deeply nested lists and possibly use that info for manipulating these kind of lists (`<-` and `[[` operations). The resulting data frame contains that kind of info. But in general, you can just think of it as assigning ranks per category when each category can have an arbitrary number of sub-categories.